# Android Bottom Nav Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to use Bottom Navigation Activity. I use the default 3 menu items with their fragments.
My problem is, I am seeing a gap between the ActionBar and the fragment. In the activity_main, I set the height to `match_parent`.

I tried to see if anyone else has this problem but could not come across.

In the `activity_main.xml` file, I have the code that comes with a creation of a new activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`bottom_nav_menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

</menu>
```

`mobile_navigation.xml`

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.zakuto.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.zakuto.myapplication.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.zakuto.myapplication.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
</navigation>
```

Below a screenshot of the screen. 
[image]

Comment: Công Hải's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62013099/3837092) worked! I removed the padding-top from the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout has a padding-top. Remove this line

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```